# Why must I have a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to implement a password-protected preferences screen.  I press the menu button then the settings button and instead of the password screen showing up, it FCs and I receive this error:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.john.websafe/com.john.websafe.Preferences}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
     <snip>
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:236)
     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onContentChanged(PreferenceActivity.java:160)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:312)
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1626)
     at com.john.websafe.Preferences.onCreate(Preferences.java:19)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
     ... 11 more
```

`Preferences.java` line 19:

```
setContentView(R.layout.password);
```

Password.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/password" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<Button android:id="@+id/confirm" 
  android:text="@string/confirm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What is causing this error?  Why do I need a listview whose id is `android.R.list`?  I don't even *have* a `ListActivity`...  Does a `PreferenceActivity` include a `ListActivity`?

Comment: Need more information in order to be able to help you. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `PreferenceActivity` is a subclass of `ListActivity` ([source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)), so you can either remove the `setContentView()` method call or add a subview with id `android.R.list` in `password.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I solved the problem by separating the Password-and-Preferences activity into an activity for the password and a `PreferenceActivity` thus meaning an activity that extends `PreferenceActivity` was not calling `setContentView()`(Basically, I did [what ZelluX said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086467/why-must-i-have-a-listview/5086518#5086518)).